# To get SubString in Groovy separated By a Character

Tags: groovy

Consider the below String

```
String names = "Bharath-Vinayak-Harish-Punith"
```

I want to get output in the form of string it contains only **Bharath**.
(String up to the first occurrence of "-" operator). Anyone can please tell me, how can be we do this?

Comment: By the way, is this homework of some sort?

Comment: No. Actually i found same type of situation while coding for my project.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the general case, I agree with the `split` method in the previous answer, but, when only returning the first string, the substring method is the same amount of work for the programmer (and, for insanely large strings, less computational work):

```
String result = names.substring(0, names.indexOf('-'))
```

Comment: well, it is working.But there many occurrence of "-" .Why it only take first index.

Comment: @BharathAN [indexOf returns the first occurrence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Groovy 2.0 (released yesterday), you can do:

```
String names = 'Bharath-Vinayak-Harish-Punith'
String result = names.takeWhile { it != '-' }
assert result == 'Bharath'
```

Comment: @BharathAN Are you using Groovy 2.0?  Do you mean the web console? The web console is running 1.8.4...

Answer (score 7):

You could use split:

```
def theName = names.split(/-/)[0]
```

split returns a String array, then get the first array element.

Comment: kelly any other methods other than split() or tokanize()

Comment: Well, you could use indexOf to find the position of the first "-" then use substring to get from the beginning of the string to the character just before the dash.  But why would you want to do this rather than using the built in functions designed to do this?

Comment: split method returns array of strings. But i dont need all the values, i need only first part.I think  simply it consumes more memory by using split method.

Comment: @BharathAN You're that worried about a few hundred bytes?

Answer (score 1):

```
def names= 'Bharath-Vinayak-Harish-Punith'   
assert "Bharath" == (names =~ /^(.*?)\-/)[0][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

in case you have the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library available (which is part of various other frameworks, e.g. Grails):

```
 def result = StringUtils.substringBefore(names, '-')
```

Best regards,
Björn