# How can I manipulate a string in environment section of Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Here is the structure of my pipeline:

```
def call(String microservice_param) {

pipeline {
    environment {
        MICROSERVICE_NAME = "${microservice_param}".split("-")[1]
    }
}
```

I would like to manipulate the string parameter as shown above but I get this error:
`Environment variable values can only be joined together with ‘+’s.`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257014/to-get-substring-in-groovy-separated-by-a-character)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't like my own solution, it does work:
define a new variable and set it prior to your pipeline block and use it in your environment.

```
def call(String microservice_param) {
  def microserv_name = microservice_param.split("-")[1]
  pipeline {
    environment {
    MICROSERVICE_NAME = "${microserv_name}"
    }
  .
  .
  .
  }
}
```

Haven't found a better solution - perhaps someone will provide it here.
Assuming you would be using more of the parameters, you'd create a new variable for each and use it in the Environment directive.  We do this for use in shared library declarative pipeline code, but use a Map for the call parameter.